# MqttBrowserClient fails to connect due to missing conack package

Tags: flutter, mqtt, flutter-web

I am trying to make webapp over flutter which will connect to HIVE broker. I took the broker name from the official website, set the port number to 8000 just like mentioned there and still get the error message as below:

> error is mqtt-client::NoConnectionException: The maximum allowed connection attempts ({1}) were exceeded. The broker is not responding to the connection request message (Missing Connection Acknowledgement?

I really have no clue how to proceed. Can someone please help?
Below is my code:

```
MqttBrowserClient mq = MqttBrowserClient(
    'wss://broker.mqttdashboard.com:8000', '',
    maxConnectionAttempts: 1);

/*

MqttBrowserClient mq = MqttBrowserClient('ws://test.mosquitto.org', 'client-1',
    maxConnectionAttempts: 1);

 */
class mqttService {
  Future<MqttBrowserClient?> connectToServer() async {
    try {
      final connMess = MqttConnectMessage()
          .withClientIdentifier('clientz5tWzoydVL')
          .authenticateAs('a14guguliye', 'z5tWzoydVL')
          .withWillTopic('willtopic')
          .withWillMessage('My Will message')
          .startClean() // Non persistent session for testing
          .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);

      mq.port = 1883;
      mq.keepAlivePeriod = 50;
      mq.connectionMessage = connMess;
      mq.websocketProtocols = MqttClientConstants.protocolsSingleDefault;
      mq.onConnected = onConnected;

      var status = await mq.connect();
      return mq;
    } catch (e) {
      print("error is " + e.toString());
      mq.disconnect();
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*That port 8000 may be open but the HiveMQ broker may not be listening.*
Make sure that the broker is fully booted and binds to that IP:Port combo.

In the HiveMQ broker startup output, you should see something similar to:

```
Started Websocket Listener on address 0.0.0.0 and on port 8000
```

If needed, the [HiveMQ Broker configuration documentation is here](https://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/3.4/user-guide/configuration.html#default-configuration).

You can use the public [HiveMQ MQTT Websocket demo client](http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/) to test your connection to make sure it's not a local code issue.

As a last option, use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) to monitor MQTT traffic with a filter of `tcp.port == 8000 and mqtt`